# How to get only clicked href values on button click?

Tags: jquery

I have multiple href links. Now, i want to get the data of only those hrefs which are clicked. So, my code looks like this.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="<?=$user['id']; ?>" class="user"></a>
```

and my jquery code looks like this.

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    $('.user').each(function() {
        console.log(this);
    });
});
```

It returns all the href even if i select only one because of each function. How to get only those href values which are selected only after a button is clicked.

Comment: why don't you use `check box` instead of `href`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you select `a` , but here is an example that may be useful to you.

Just put `selected` class ( or any other class name ) to selected `a`.

```js
$(".user").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});

$('#button').click(function () {
    console.clear(); // optional 
    $('.user.selected').each(function() {
        console.log(this);
    });
});
```

```css
a{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ddd;
}

a.selected{
  background: #0095ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="1" class="user">1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="2" class="user">2</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="3" class="user">3</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="4" class="user">4</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="5" class="user">5</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="6" class="user">6</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="7" class="user">7</a>

<button id="button">GO</button>
```